# How are keyboard inputs transmitted through Windows terminal and WSL2

Tags: emacs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

I'm using WSL (WSL2 in fact) for a few days and I'm a bit confuse about keyboard combination redirection and/or interception.

I have to say that my favorite tool to edit text is emacs, that use a lot of keyword combinations.

My stack is this one :

- Under windows, I run Windows terminal (WT.exe)
- In this terminal I open a tab which (afaik magically) is a shell on a linux subsystem. This subsystem is a Debian
- In this shell I run emacs.

The whole thing looks like that :[image: WT.exe calling WSL2 calling emacs]

At this point, when I enter a key combination, it may be passed to emacs, or it may be intercepted/interpreted by any other layer of the stack.

For instance :

- ctrl-e is interpreted by emacs : it move the caret to the end of file
- ctrl-z is interpreted by wsl2 (afaik) : it pauses emacs as a background job
- ctrl-tab is interpreted by windows terminal : it changes tab
- alt-f4 is interpreted by windows : it closes windows terminal

And some of them are a mystery for me. For instance ctrl-_ (ctrl underscore), which is very useful on default emacs configuration, is not interpreted by emacs. It is translated at some point as "delete". In this configuration typing "delete" or "ctrl-_" is the very same thing : it removes the first character before the caret.

Very specifically and synthetically stated, my question would be : "How do I configure this stack to make emacs receive ctrl-_ ?"

Of course more generally, I really would like to know, how each layer works and is parameterized. For instance, is there a configuration file for WT and/or WSL2, that says which combination are forwarded, which one are interpreted and which one are ignored.

Additional Data :

- If I run WSL2 through WT, but don't start emacs, ctrl-_ is also interpreted as "delete"
- If I run another type of "tab" in WT, like cmd.exe or powershell, ctrl-_ is not interpreted as "delete". I don't know if it is interpreted at all
- If I run WSL2 without WT, Ctrl-_ is not interpreted at all.
- I didn't found any mention of ctrl-_ in WT config shortcuts.

Additional Data :
I tried to run following python program in both stacks : WT/WSL and WT/CMD.EXE

```
import keyboard
while(True):
  c = keyboard.read_key()
  print(c)
```

On WT/CMD.EXE, the output is :

```
ctrl
_
_
ctrl
```

Which means it receive the keyboard info.

On WT/WSL2, it fails to run. Apparently "keyboard" is not compatible with WSL2. But this is not the question here.

Comment: I have the same issue, it is also linked with the french layout I guess as my collegues using US one can use emacs with no issue. I opened an issue on wsl GitHUB https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/11041. I ca use emacs correctly within a linux native terminal (eg. terminator installed in wsl distro)

Answer (score 2):

A useful tool for debugging input on linux is `showkey -a`. You can use that to help debug what keys the client application is receiving. If you press a key and it doesn't display anything in the output, then there's a good chance it's being  intercepted by the Terminal.

There's probably an open issue for this on the [Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) repo. [#8458](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/8458) looks similar.

> is there a configuration file for WT and/or WSL2, that says which combination are forwarded, which one are interpreted and which one are ignored.

[defaults.json](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/main/src/cascadia/TerminalSettingsModel/defaults.json) is the file that contains all the keybindings that the Windows Terminal binds by default.

What WSL does is more complicated. IIRC, the `inputrc` file on linux is used  `readline` (for `bash`, etc) to specify how certain keys are handled by the shell. But then there are also keys configured in `stty` that control other parts of the TTY interface. That part I understand less.

> alt-f4 is interpreted by windows : it closes windows terminal

FWIW That's actually a application-level keybinding. The Terminal handles that key manually, so that people can optionally disable it. See [defaults.json](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/blob/92f0700d5d7e89141eba225442810519a4d10235/src/cascadia/TerminalSettingsModel/defaults.json#L282)